# Python / Windows: List only USB removable drives

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, drive

Is possible to get only the removable USB drives and (not so necessary) their tags on Windows using Python? On Linux (Ubuntu), you only need to list the `/media` folder.

Here's my current code (it lists all available drives letters including system drive, cd/dvd drives, etc):

```
import win32api

dv = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
dv = dv.split('\000')[:-1]
print dv
```

The result is something like this:
`['C:\\', 'D:\\', 'E:\\']`

I'd like only the USB mass storage drives... any help?

Regards...

Comment: `/media` can contain more than just USB devices. HDD can be there, too.

Comment: i know but that's just an example and it get the drives tags, also, it won't list the system drive :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a list of removable drives plugged in the computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465580/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-removable-drives-plugged-in-the-computer)

Answer (score 1):

```
import win32file

def rdrive(d):
    # returns boolean, true if drive d is removable
    return win32file.GetDriveType(d)==win32file.DRIVE_REMOVABLE
```

Comment: `No module named 'win32file'`

Comment: `pip install pywin32`

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar question myself.  Using logic from @user2532756's answer, I knocked together this quick function for any new visitors to this question:

Very basically, just call the function and it will return a `list` of all **removable drives** to the caller.

```
import win32api
import win32con
import win32file

def get_removable_drives():
    drives = [i for i in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\x00') if i]
    rdrives = [d for d in drives if win32file.GetDriveType(d) == win32con.DRIVE_REMOVABLE]
    return rdrives
```

**For example:**  A call to `get_removable_drives()` will output:

```
['E:\\']
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this too, but then made it "from scratch" using the `wmi` module.

```
import wmi

LOCAL_MACHINE_CONNECTION = wmi.WMI()

# .Win32_LogicalDisk() returns a list of wmi_object objects. Each of them represents a storage device connected to the local machine (serial number, path, description, e.t.c)
drives_available = [wmi_object.deviceID for wmi_object in LOCAL_MACHINE_CONNECTION.Win32_LogicalDisk() if wmi_object.description == "Removable Disk"]

# .deviceID is the tag (or letter like F:, G:)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ctypes module to get the removable drives list.

```
from ctypes import windll    
def get_drives():
        drives = []
        bitmask = windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
        for letter in map(chr, range(65, 91)):
            if bitmask & 1:
                drives.append(letter)
            bitmask >>= 1
        return drives
```

You can take the same list and compare it with fresh list of drives to get removable drives added .

```
    drives_list=get_drives()
    drives_list1=[]
    while True:
      drives_list1=get_drives()
      if len(list(set(drives_list1) - set(drives_list))) > 0:
            print("Drives Added"+str(set(drives_list1) - set(drives_list)))
```

For more refer this repo [drivemonitoring](https://github.com/ajaykumarkk/DriveMonitoring) on github.

Answer (score 0):

The `psutil` library is much better than `win32api`. It provides lots of information about the drives and nicely formatted. https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil

```
import psutils as p
externals = [i.mountpoint for i in p.disk_partitions() if 'removable' in i.opts]
```