# How can I get a list of removable drives plugged in the computer?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, drive

I would like to get a list of the removable drivers that are plugged into the computer.

How can I do that with the [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) module in Python?

Note: It's important that I will be able to separate the removable drives from the fixed drives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm is straightforward:

- Call [[MS.Docs]: GetGetLogicalDriveStringsW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlogicaldrivestringsw), which will return a string containing all the existing *rootdirs* (e.g. *C:\\*) separated by *NUL* (*\x00*) *char*s

  - Iterate over the *rootdirs* and get each one's type using [[MS.Docs]: GetDriveTypeW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypew)
  - Filter the removable drives (having the type *DRIVE_REMOVABLE*)

This is how it looks in *Python* (using *PyWin32* wrappers). Add any of *win32con.DRIVE_** constants to *drive_types* tuple to get different drive types combinations:

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

import win32con as wcon
from win32api import GetLogicalDriveStrings
from win32file import GetDriveType


def get_drives_list(drive_types=(wcon.DRIVE_REMOVABLE,)):
    drives_str = GetLogicalDriveStrings()
    drives = (item for item in drives_str.split("\x00") if item)
    return [item[:2] for item in drives if not drive_types or GetDriveType(item) in drive_types]


def main(*argv):
    drive_filters_examples = (
        (None, "All"),
        ((wcon.DRIVE_REMOVABLE,), "Removable"),
        ((wcon.DRIVE_FIXED, wcon.DRIVE_CDROM), "Fixed and CDROM"),
    )
    for drive_types_tuple, display_text in drive_filters_examples:
        drives = get_drives_list(drive_types=drive_types_tuple)
        print("{:s} drives:".format(display_text))
        for drive in drives:
            print("{:s}  ".format(drive), end="")
        print("\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```py
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q041465580]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> All drives:
> C:  D:  E:  F:  G:  H:  I:  L:  M:  N:
>
> Removable drives:
> H:  I:
>
> Fixed and CDROM drives:
> C:  D:  E:  F:  G:  L:  M:  N:
>
>
> Done.
> ```

As a side note, in my environment (at this point):

- ***D:*** is a partition on an external (*USB*) *HDD*
- ***H:***, ***I:*** are partitions on a bootable *USB* stick (*UEFI*)
- The rest are partitions on the (internal) *SSD* and / or *HDD* disks

Comment: provide information about the dependencies and how to install them.

Comment: This is not working for larger, USB connected, terabyte sizes external drives - which are reported as fixed.

Comment: @576i:  That's probably due to a misinterpretation of *DRIVE\_REMOVABLE* / *DRIVE\_FIXED* meaning. Looking at the table from the 2nd *URL*, it turns out it's correct.

Comment: @OmidAtaollahi: Question is tagged with *PyWin32*, so that's the only dependency. `python -m pip install pywin32`. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631512/pywin32-and-python-3-8-0/58632354#58632354 for some interesting insights.

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar question myself.  Isolating @CristiFati's answer to only removable drives, I knocked together this quick (very simple) function for any new visitors to this question:

Basically, just call the function and it will return a `list` of all **removable drives** to the caller.

```
import win32api
import win32con
import win32file

def get_removable_drives():
    drives = [i for i in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\x00') if i]
    rdrives = [d for d in drives if win32file.GetDriveType(d) == win32con.DRIVE_REMOVABLE]
    return rdrives
```

**For example:**  A call to `get_removable_drives()` will output:

```
['E:\\']
```