# PyWin32 and Python 3.8.0

Tags: python, windows, dll, pywin32, python-3.8

*Python 3.8.0* has been recently released (on *20191014*, and can be downloaded from [[Python]: Python 3.8.0](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380)). 
*PyWin32* has builds for it on [[PyPI]: pywin32 225](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/225/#files) (released on *20190915*). Unfortunately, after `pip install`ing, it doesn't work.

Sample:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058631512]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe"
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import win32api
> >>> ^Z
>
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.08.00_test0\Scripts\python.exe"
> Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import win32api
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified module could not be found.
> >>> ^Z
> ```

**Notes**:

- For *Python 3.7*, I also upgraded my *PyWin32* module to the latest, and it works
- Older *PyWin32* versions work on older *Python* versions (*2.7*, *3.5*, *3.6*)
- Reproducible on *64bit* and *32bit*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Spoiler alert!!!

Applied ***#2.2.*** (from below) to the original *.whl*s, and published them on **[[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/PyWin32/v225](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/PyWin32/v225)** (*win_amd64*, *win32* for *Python 3.8*).

After installing (one of) them, existing code should work *OOTB* (with respect to this issue).

**Install steps**:

1. Download the *.whl* that matches your *Python* architecture (*064bit*, *032bit* - for more details on getting *Python* architecture, check [[SO]: How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053286/4788546) (the question is about *OSX*, but other platforms are covered as well)), it will most likely be *64bit* (*win_amd64*), from the above *URL*. 
   For example, I downloaded it in *L:\Downloads*
2. Invoke the *PIP* installer on it ([[SO]: How to install a package for a specific Python version on Windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883242/4788546)). Something like:

   ```
   (${path_to_your})python.exe -m pip ${path_to_the_downloaded_pywin32_whl}
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.00_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip "L:\Downloads\pywin32-225-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl"
   ```

---

The problem has been reported on [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - python 3.8](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1327).

The above *URL* references 2 more:

- [[Python 3.8.Docs]: What’s New In Python 3.8 - Changes in the Python API](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#changes-in-the-python-api) which states (**emphasis** is mine):

  > - **DLL dependencies for extension modules and DLLs loaded with [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) on Windows** are now resolved more securely. Only the system paths, the directory containing the DLL or PYD file, and directories added with [add_dll_directory()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory) are searched for load-time dependencies. **Specifically, PATH and the current working directory are no longer used, and modifications to these will no longer have any effect on normal DLL resolution.**
- [[Python 3.Docs]: os.add_dll_directory(path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory) which states (**emphasis** still mine):

  > This search path is used **when resolving dependencies for imported extension modules** (the module itself is resolved through `sys.path`), **and also by [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)**.

In the same time, I did some digging of my own and discovered that (for *win32api.pyd*) it's *pywintypes38.dll* (which is a dependency for the *.pyd*s) that is not found (I also specified this in a comment on the issue).

**Solutions** (actually workarounds (more or less) until an official and backwards compatible fix is released):

1. Force *pywintypes38.dll* load by importing it (as it's also a *Python* module and in this scenario it doesn't fall under the above rule) **before** any *PyWin32* module:

   ```py
   import pywintypes
   import win32api
   ```

   If working with *COM*, you'd need `import pythoncom`
2. Adding *pywin32_system32* to the *.dll* search paths (following the new model from above). There are multiple ways:

   1. *v-python*'s comment from the issue *URL* which provides a small snippet (I didn't test it)
   2. I also submitted **[[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Support for Python 3.8](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/pull/1430)**, where I do everything in the *pywin32.pth* file ("executed" when the interpreter starts, so no changes needed for existing code). Unfortunately, there is a problem with the *AppVeyor* automated tests which fail (but for some other reasons), so it has been stuck there for a while. Note that in the meantime, **the *PR* was closed and another (similar) approach was pushed. Note that *v226* (released on *20191110*) which contains the fix, does not work on *VirtualEnv*** ([[SO]: PyWin32 (226) and virtual environments (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58805300/4788546)). 
      Anyway, applying the changes locally <sup>***(1)***</sup> (on both my *Python* *VirtualEnv*s), solved the problem (on one, and didn't break the other):

      > ```
      > [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058631512]> sopr.bat
      > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
      >
      > [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import win32api"
      >
      > [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.08.00_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import win32api"
      >
      > [prompt]>
      > ```
   3. Other ways like copying the *.dll*s (e.g. in *%SystemRoot%\System32*), or *SymLink*ing them, but (personally) I wouldn't recommend those

Check:

- [[SO]: Can't import dll module in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333711/4788546) for more details on *.dll* loading (via *CTypes*)
- [[SO]: Is the function os. add_dll_directory() adding directories permanently? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67811071/4788546)
- [[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546)

---

#### Update *#0*

**[[PyPI]: pywin32 227](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/227)** (which addresses this issue), was published on *20191114*!

---

#### Footnotes

- ***#1.***: Check [[SO]: Run / Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989490/4788546) (**Patching *UTRunner*** section) for how to apply patches (on *Win*).

Comment: @Thingamabobs: I don't know what your issue is, as your *URL* points to this post.

Comment: Sorry was the wrong [link. Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70543669/13629335) is my question.

Answer (score -4):

Managed to install pywin32 v225 with pycharm on python 3.8.

importing *pywintypes* before *win32api*

```
import pywintypes
import win32api
```

Comment: This doesn't qualify as an answer.