# How to fix the errors while compiling Python 3.2.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-3.2

I am trying to create Python-3.2.0 virtual environment for upgrading my tool.
The tool was earlier built with 2.7.15 version. Now I want to upgrade it to Python-3.2.0

These are the steps which I followed on Cent-OS:

(a) Download the Python source code from the official repository
            cd /tmp
            wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.2/Python-3.2.tgz
            tar -xvf Python-3.2
            cd Python-3.2

(b) Compile Python with the required flags
    ./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared -- 
     prefix=/opt/python LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/opt/python/lib
    sudo make install

I got the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/install -c python-config /opt/python/bin/python3.2m-config
    rm python-config
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/Python-3.2: ./python -E ./setup.py install \
            --prefix=/opt/python \
            --install-scripts=/opt/python/bin \
            --install-platlib=/opt/python/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload \
            --root=/
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building dbm using ndbm
    INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers
    building '_dbm' extension
    gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_NDBM_H -IInclude -I/opt/python/include -I. -I./Include -I/usr/local/include -I/tmp/Python-3.2 -c /tmp/Python-3.2/Modules/_dbmmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/tmp/Python-3.2/Modules/_dbmmodule.o
I   n file included from Include/Python.h:111:0,
                    from /tmp/Python-3.2/Modules/_dbmmodule.c:6:
    Include/modsupport.h:27:1: warning: ‘_PyArg_ParseTuple_SizeT’ is an unrecognized format function type [-Wformat=]
    PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyArg_ParseTuple(PyObject *, const char *, ...) Py_FORMAT_PARSETUPLE(PyArg_ParseTuple, 2, 3);
    ^
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-rpath=/opt/python/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/tmp/Python-3.2/Modules/_dbmmodule.o -L. -L/opt/python/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lpython3.2m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/_dbm.cpython-32m.so
    *** WARNING: renaming "_dbm" since importing it failed: build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/_dbm.cpython-32m.so: undefined symbol: dbm_nextkey

    Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
    _tkinter           bz2                ossaudiodev
    To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


    Failed to build these modules:
    _dbm

    running build_scripts
    copying and adjusting /tmp/Python-3.2/Tools/scripts/pydoc3 -> build/scripts-3.2
    copying and adjusting /tmp/Python-3.2/Tools/scripts/idle3 -> build/scripts-3.2
    copying and adjusting /tmp/Python-3.2/Tools/scripts/2to3 -> build/scripts-3.2
    changing mode of build/scripts-3.2/pydoc3 from 644 to 755
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to start by saying that what you're trying to do, is an exercise of futility. Check:

- [[Python]: PEP 373 -- Python 2.7 Release Schedule](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0392)
- [[Python]: PEP 392 -- Python 3.2 Release Schedule](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0392)

So:

1. You're trying to "upgrade" from a version that's going out of support at the end of the year (your particular flavor (*v2.7.**15***) released last year) to a version **that has been dead for several years**
2. More: you're attempting *v3.2.**0*** which is the very 1<sup>st</sup> one of that series

Quickly searching for your error revealed:

- [[Python.Bugs]: _dbm not building on Fedora 17](https://bugs.python.org/issue15044)
- [[Python.Bugs]: Failure to build _dbm with ndbm on Arch Linux](https://bugs.python.org/issue14185)

Now, this may or may not be the cause in your case. If it is, there is a fix, but you **won't benefit from it because of *#2.***.

A couple of ideas:

- Generally, a software's 1<sup>st</sup> version of a series is likely to have more bugs, because it hasn't been tested much "in the real world" (as it hasn't been released yet). The chances of something going wrong increase if there is other software that is built on top of it (in this case, other *Python* 3<sup>rd</sup>-party modules). As an example (although not related to the current scenario), you could check [[SO]: PyWin32 and Python 3.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631512/pywin32-and-python-3-8-0)
- You should use a (*Python*) version that's supported and maintained (e.g. ***v3.8***, or ***v3.7***), so that you could have a real chance of getting help if running into problems
- If for some reasons (that I fail to find logical) you need to stick to the *v3.2*, try at least using the latest one ([[Python]: Python-3.2.6.tgz](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.2.6/Python-3.2.6.tgz))