# PyWin32 (226) and virtual environments

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, pywin32

[[PyPI]: pywin32 226](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/226/#files) has been released on *20191110*. 
It **works** on most of the *Python* installations (*e.g.* works on the official versions downloaded from [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads)), but **not** on virtual environments (*e.g.* **created with *VirtualEnv* (*v16.7.7***), and (based on further research) *Python*'s ***venv***). 
I used *Python* ***v3.8***.0 and ***v3.7***.3 as lab rats. Here's the output for the former:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058805040]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.08.00_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import win32api"
> Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
> Python runtime state: initialized
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.08.00_test0\lib\site.py", line 769, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.08.00_test0\lib\site.py", line 746, in main
>     paths_in_sys = addsitepackages(paths_in_sys)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.08.00_test0\lib\site.py", line 279, in addsitepackages
>     addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.08.00_test0\lib\site.py", line 202, in addsitedir
>     addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.08.00_test0\lib\site.py", line 170, in addpackage
>     exec(line)
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.08.00_test0\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywin32_bootstrap.py", line 14, in <module>
>     for maybe in site.getsitepackages():
> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'site' has no attribute 'getsitepackages' (most likely due to a circular import)
> ```

Comment: Raise an issue on their repo?

Comment: Not an answer, I haven't tested it, and the issue might still be present... Have you considered using [Python's standard _venv_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) instead? (assuming you meant that you have been using [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) so far)

Comment: @sinoroc: To be honest, I didn't (thanks for the suggestion!). I will give it a shot, although I'm expecting everythiong to work *OK*.

Comment: @sinoroc: Did some quick tests and the behavior is exactly as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631512/pywin32-and-python-3-8-0. Updated the *PR* that I've submitted to handle that case too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note**: I branched this answer (and also the question) from [[SO]: PyWin32 and Python 3.8.0 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632354/4788546), as it's a different issue. You might want to check that one before going further.

After some digging, it turns out it's a ***VirtualEnv* bug** (or at least, that's how I see things, because *VirtualEnv*'s *site.py* doesn't contain *getsitepackages* - although it was present in *Python*'s *site.py* since *v2.7*). 
There are several issues (that were) open revolving this absence (*e.g.* [[GitHub]: pypa/virtualenv - site.getsitepackages() missing](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/737)), but they appear to be closed without a fix (many of them due to inactivity). Also, [[GitHub]: [WIP] The next-gen virtualenv (rewrite)](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/1377) which is a big refactor, doesn't seem to address it.

***Recap***: this error (in ***VirtualEnv*** context):

- Also applies to other *Python* versions (I can confirm for *v3.7.3* (*32bit*))
- Happens every time when the interpreter starts

In conclusion, **do not install *PyWin32 226* in (*VirtualEnv*) virtual environments, as they will end up in a broken state!**

*PyWin32* (official *.whl*s) "compatibility table" (didn't check *Anaconda* (or other such tools)):

- "Normal" (official) *Python* installations:

  - *v226* is *OK*
- *VirtualEnv*s (and also *Python*'s standard *venv*s):

  - *v22**5*** is *OK*
  - For *Python 3.8.0*, [[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/PyWin32/v225](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/PyWin32/v225) should be used

Submitted **[[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Workaround for virtual environments (VirtualEnv)](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/pull/1442)** (**merged on *20191114***). Applying the changes locally (check the referenced question for details on how to do it), fixed it:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q058805040]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> ".\venv_py_064_030800\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip list
> Package    Version
> ---------- -------
> pip        19.3.1
> pywin32    226
> setuptools 41.6.0
> wheel      0.33.6
>
> [prompt]> ".\venv_py_064_030800\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import win32api"
>
> [prompt]>
> ```

---

#### Update *#0*

**[[PyPI]: pywin32 227](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/227)** (which addresses this issue), was published on *20191114*!

Comment: Thanks! You resolved by problem at least ;) Downgrading pywin32 version resolves it.