# Why are .pth files loaded twice in a Python virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-venv

In the user site .pth files are processed once at interpreter startup:

```
$ echo 'import sys; sys.stdout.write("hello world\n")' > ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hello.pth
$ python3.8 -c ""
hello world
```

And it's the same behaviour in the system site, e.g. `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`.

But in venv they are processed ***twice***:

```
$ rm ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hello.pth
$ /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -m venv .venv
$ source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) $ echo 'import sys; sys.stdout.write("hello world\n")' > .venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hello.pth
(.venv) $ python -c ""
hello world
hello world
```

Why are path configuration files processed twice in a virtual environment?

Comment: Seems like there are still issues related to virtual environments (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805040/pywin32-226-and-virtual-environments).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it all happens in the `site` module (not so surprising). In particular in the [`site.main()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/site.py#L548) function.

The loading of the `.pth` files happens either in [`site.addsitepackages()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/site.py#L346) or in [`site.addusersitepackages()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/site.py#L305), depending in which folder the file is placed. Well more precisely both these function call [`site.addpackage()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/site.py#L148), where it [actually happens](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/site.py#L169).

In your first example, outside a *virtual environment*, the file is placed in the directory for user site packages. So the console output happens when [`site.main()` calls `site.addusersitepackages()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/site.py#L566).

In the second example, within a *virtual environment*, the file is placed in the virtual environment's own *site packages* directory. So the console output happens when [`site.main()` calls `site.addsitepackages()` directly](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/site.py#L567) and also via [`site.venv()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/site.py#L563) a couple of lines earlier that also calls [`site.addsitepackages()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/site.py#L495) if it [detects that the interpreter is running inside a virtual environment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/site.py#L476), i.e. if it [finds a `pyvenv.cfg` file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/site.py#L467).

So in short: inside a virtual environment `site.addsitepackages()` runs twice.

As to what the intention is for this behavior, there is a [note](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/site.py#L494):

```
        # Doing this here ensures venv takes precedence over user-site
        addsitepackages(known_paths, [sys.prefix])
```

Which, from what I can tell, matters in case the virtual environment has been configured to allow [*system site packages*](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/site.py#L499).

Maybe it could have been solved differently so that the *path configuration* files are not loaded twice.

Comment: Good analysis. Looks like very hacky coding in `site.py`, I guess they don't care about [ab]uses of `.pth` files apart from the normal use-case of extending `sys.path` (which will be de-duplicated by `site.py` also). I advise you to permalink all these source references to git tag, e.g. [like this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Lib/site.py#L563) instead of [like this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/site.py#L563), so that they don't get lost when the 3.8 branch receives new commits.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point about the links. Maybe the behavior is not intentional (loaded twice instead of just once), and it should be raised as an issue.