# Python ctypes use winmode to load DLLs

Tags: python, ctypes

I've installed an C++ API application which puts a couple of DLLs (`A.DLL` and `B.DLL`) in my programs folder. `A.DLL` has a dependency on `B.DLL`

I can load them successfully with `ctypes.WinDLL` IF from the installation folder like `C:\Programs Files\XXX-API\A.DLL`

while if I move the folder to another place `C:\TEMP\` , the Python cytes load will complain that it can't find `B.DLL`.

I'm looking into the [winmode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.WinDLL), looks like it will solve the problem. The `winmode` seems to take an integer from parameters in [MS reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa) .

for example :

> LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR
>
> 0x00000100

To use `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR` ,to pass `0x00000100` as `256` to `winmode`  ? ctype will complain can not find `B.DLL`,I'm not sure what's missing ,appreciate any idea from you ,thanks !

```
ctypes.WinDLL(path_to_A_DLL , winmode = 256 )
```

Comment: What *Python* version are you using? What do you mean by "*to pass `0x00000002` as `256` to `winmode`*" (as it makes no sense)? Also post the stacktrace. Doesn't your last snippet work?

Comment: @CristiFati thanks, I am using python3.8 . It was a typo.  Should be `0x00000100` ( `256` in decmial ). Just Python complain can't find `B.DLL`.

Comment: I imagined. First of all, how do you know it's *B.dll* that's not found? Please add the stacktrace. Second, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631512/pywin32-and-python-3-8-0/58632354#58632354. It seems different, but I think it's the same issue (so I can mark this as a duplicate). Let me know how it works out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative 1:

```
import nt
_func1 = ctypes.WinDLL(lib_name, winmode = nt._LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR)
```

Alternative 2:

```
_func1 = ctypes.WinDLL(lib_name, winmode = 0x100)
```

Should both work.

But was trying os.add_dll_directory() all day long. Switched finally to

```
_func1 = ctypes.WinDLL(absolute_lib_path, winmode = 0x8)
```

Comment: Last version worked for me. As I understand 0x8 corresponds to LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexw)) but is not available in `nt` module.