# Dll not loaded or recognize in visual studio python

Tags: python, visual-studio, dll, path

I am currently working on a I2C project that needs a dll.
But there is something I don't understand while debuging the program I get an error that said:

```
Could not find module 'libMPSSE.dll'. Try using the full path with constructor syntax.


    File "D:\Users\h\OneDrive - h\Bureau\projet.py\EXE_newProtocol_I2C_V7.py", line 418, in <module>
        libMPSSE = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libMPSSE.dll")
```

Then I tried this command:

```
os.add_dll_directory('D:\Users\h\OneDrive - h\Bureau\projet.py\libMPSSE.dll')
```

And this command:

```
libMPSSE = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("D:\Users\h\OneDrive - h\Bureau\projet.py\libMPSSE.dll")
```

But I am not sure if it detects the `dll` because of this:

[project folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ybgi.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014318/filenotfounderror-could-not-find-module-libvlc-dll