# Error: Could not find module 'C:\Users\phong\Desktop\Python\libvlc.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax

Tags: python, vlc, python-vlc

I have a code like this

```
import vlc
player = vlc.MediaPlayer("a.mp4")
player.play()
```

and it give me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\phong\Desktop\Python\Media player\media_player.py", line 1, in <module>
    import vlc
  File "C:\Users\phong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 210, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "C:\Users\phong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 170, in find_lib
    dll = ctypes.CDLL('.\\' + libname)
  File "C:\Users\phong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\phong\Desktop\Python\libvlc.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'libvlc.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014318/filenotfounderror-could-not-find-module-libvlc-dll)

Answer (score 0):

download VLC 3.0.8
and unpack libvlc.dll、libvlccore.dll and plugins to the path "c:\windows\system32",
but make sure vlc is 64 bits in case your python is 64 bits
you can download from this address:
http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/