# Cannot import from pywinauto: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32ui: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: python, pywinauto

After installing pywinauto I'm trying to run that simple code:

```
from pywinauto import Application

filename = 'notepad.exe'
app = aplication.Application().start(filename)
```

And get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\auto\retr\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pywinauto import Application
  File "D:\Users\222\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from . import findwindows
  File "D:\Users\222\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import controls
  File "D:\Users\222\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import uiawrapper # register "uia" back-end (at the end of uiawrapper module)
  File "D:\Users\222\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .. import backend
  File "D:\Users\222\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\backend.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .base_wrapper import BaseWrapper
  File "D:\Users\222\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 44, in <module>
    import win32ui
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32ui: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

If I do import of win32ui explicitly:

```
import win32ui
from pywinauto import Application
```

The error got simpler, but still nothing to do with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\auto\retr\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import win32ui
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32ui: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

I googled similar issues, but did not find any solution..

I have Win10, python 3.9

Comment: Just running into this today. I ran the post install: `python "c:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py" -install` which put DLL files into `c:\WINDOWS\system32`, but that had no effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use win32ui with pywin32 gives: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444740/trying-to-use-win32ui-with-pywin32-gives-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initializ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would appear this is a duplicate of [Trying to use win32ui with pywin32 gives: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444740)

From the looks of that and [the Github page](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1593), `import win32ui` is actually broken on Python 3.9 using pywin32 build 228. There is a workaround posted in the other question. The short story is that build 229 is preferred, and until that release, the Github page has a workaround by manually installing a fork of the 228 build that is patched or a manual version of the 229 build.

For convenience, the *.whls* can be found [here](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/PyWin32/v228). Download the appropriate file and use:

```
pip install -U --force-reinstall <FILE>.whl
```

and the problem will most likely be fixed.

Comment: That's really helped. I did manual reinstall of pywin32-228-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl and now it works.Thanks a lot!