# How to take screenshot using pywinauto in python

Tags: python, windows, date, time, pywinauto

Can anyone please help me with python code to capture the attached image:

[image]

Comment: Kindly note that clicking on the link will pop the image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

pip install pywinauto 
pip install Pillow

```
from pywinauto import Desktop, Application
app = Application().start(r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe') 
win = app['UntitledNotepad'] 
win.type_keys('hello world') 
win.capture_as_image().save('screenshot.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code -

```
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application
from PIL import ImageGrab

# connect to task bar
app = Application().Connect(title=u'', class_name='Shell_TrayWnd')

# Get task bar window
shelltraywnd = app.Shell_TrayWnd

# Get tray clock window
trayclockwclass = shelltraywnd.TrayClockWClass

# Get rectangle of tray clock window
clockRect = trayclockwclass.client_rect()

# Click into the rectangle of tray clock window
trayclockwclass.click_input(coords=(clockRect.left+20, clockRect.bottom-20))

# wait for Clock Flyout to appear
time.sleep(5)

# Grab the top screen
screenBuffer = ImageGrab.grab()

# Save Path/filename
save_path = "yourScreen.jpg"

# Save into file
screenBuffer.save(save_path)
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin Patole for the reply.  I am experiencing the below error while running the line - "from pywinauto.application import Application" : 'ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32ui: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.'

Comment: Refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64655079/cannot-import-from-pywinauto-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-win32