# Is the function os. add_dll_directory() adding directories permanently?

Tags: python, dll

For loading DLL libraries in Python 3.8+ I understand the the path environemnt variable is not used anymore to search for dependencies. Therefore the function os. add_dll_directory() should be used to add directories to the search path. That works on my machine.

Is it possible that the directories are added permanently? I have noticed that now everything is loaded correctly also without adding the dll directory first using the function mentioned. I cannot reproduce the error where the dependencies were not found.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory) I did not understand that anything is changed permanently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[Python.Docs]: os.add_dll_directory(path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory) calls [[MS.Docs]: AddDllDirectory function (libloaderapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory) which states (**emphasis** is mine):

> Adds a directory to the **process** DLL search path.

So, it has effect during the lifetime of the calling process, or (according to *Python* *doc*) until the returned object is closed (in that case *RemoveDllDirectory* is called under the hood) either manually or at *with* statement exit.

Related (more or less):

- [[SO]: PyWin32 and Python 3.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58631512/4788546)
- [[SO]: OSError: Cannot find pyvips library (DLLs) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73934513/4788546)

Comment: Just for everybodys information: It seems that Python 3.8 and 3.9 behave differently in this regard. While I need to call the add_dll_directory function in 3.8, it works without it in 3.9.