# OSError: Cannot find pyvips library (DLLs)

Tags: python, dll

I'm facing a problem where I can't import pyvips as the OS doesn't find the directory where all the DLLs are located.

```
>>> import pyvips
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\istab\.virtualenvs\RPAS_DS_UI-v4ujo25h\lib\site-packages\pyvips\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _libvips
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_libvips'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\istab\.virtualenvs\RPAS_DS_UI-v4ujo25h\lib\site-packages\pyvips\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    gobject_lib = ffi.dlopen(_gobject_libname)
  File "C:\Users\istab\.virtualenvs\RPAS_DS_UI-v4ujo25h\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 150, in dlopen
    lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)
  File "C:\Users\istab\.virtualenvs\RPAS_DS_UI-v4ujo25h\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 832, in _make_ffi_library
    backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)
  File "C:\Users\istab\.virtualenvs\RPAS_DS_UI-v4ujo25h\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 828, in _load_backend_lib
    return backend.load_library(path, flags)
OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Users\istab\RPAS_2\RPAS_DS_UI\vips-dev-8.13\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll': error 0x7e
```

I followed the documentation [Here](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) and added the bin folder to `PATH` yet the same problem occurs. And it is not my first time having problems with packages' DLLs :')

Any thoughts?

Comment: How did you install (build) the package?

Comment: @CristiFati using `pip install pyvips`, and it got installed successfully.

Comment: What if before `import pyvips` you have `os.add_dll_directory("c:\\vips-dev-8.7\\bin")` (or whatever path you installed *LibVIPS* in)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [[SO]: PyWin32 and Python 3.8.0 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632354/4788546), but i'm going to add some details.

[[PyPI]: pyvips 2.2.1](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/2.2.1) (*Non-conda install* section) states:

> To set `PATH` from within Python, you need something like this at the start:
>
> ```py
> import os
> vipshome = 'c:\\vips-dev-8.7\\bin'
> os.environ['PATH'] = vipshome + ';' + os.environ['PATH']
> ```
>
> Now when you import pyvips, it should be able to find the DLLs.

This is no longer correct (starting with *Python 3.**8*** - check the 1<sup>st</sup> *URL* why).
But *PyVIPS* (*v2.2.1* - latest at answer time) **doesn't support *Python 3.8*** (highest is *v3.**6***).

For *Python 3.8*+ compatibility (and also maintaining the old one), the above snippet should be (text would also need some changes):

```py
import os
add_dll_dir = getattr(os, "add_dll_directory", None)
vipsbin = r"c:\vips-dev-8.7\bin"  # LibVIPS binary dir
if callable(add_dll_dir):
    add_dll_dir(vipsbin)
else:
    os.environ["PATH"] = os.pathsep.join((vipsbin, os.environ["PATH"]))

import pyvips
```

Created [[GitHub]: libvips/pyvips - Update install steps for Python 3.8+](https://github.com/libvips/pyvips/issues/351) to track this (fixed on *221003*).

Might be useful to read:

- [[SO]: How PyCharm imports differently than system command prompt (Windows) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55083046/4788546)
- [[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546)

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem to work anymore after forced company windows10 21H2 update.
get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyvips'

Even installed latest python:

```
C:\Users\maja>python
Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Even installed vips-dev-8.13

Is it a 32/64 bit problem?

For some reason, which was not working yesterday, pyvips does install!?

```
C:\Data\techtime\Houston>pip install pyvips
Collecting pyvips
  Using cached pyvips-2.2.1.tar.gz (633 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting cffi>=1.0.0
  Using cached cffi-1.15.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (179 kB)
Collecting pycparser
  Using cached pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, pyvips
  DEPRECATION: pyvips is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for pyvips ... done
Successfully installed cffi-1.15.1 pycparser-2.21 pyvips-2.2.1
```

Using proposed PATH include:

```
import os
add_dll_dir = getattr(os, "add_dll_directory", None)
vipsbin = r"c:\vips-dev-8.13\bin"  # LibVIPS binary dir
if callable(add_dll_dir):
    add_dll_dir(vipsbin)
else:
    os.environ["PATH"] = os.pathsep.join((vipsbin, os.environ["PATH"]))

import pyvips as py
```

Now I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyvips\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _libvips
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_libvips'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data\techtime\Houston\houston-compare-v2.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pyvips as py
  File "C:\Users\maja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyvips\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    gobject_lib = ffi.dlopen(_gobject_libname)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\maja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 150, in dlopen
    lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\maja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 832, in _make_ffi_library
    backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\maja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 827, in _load_backend_lib
    raise OSError(msg)
OSError: cannot load library 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll'
```

**Guess what's the solution: uninstalled python and installed v 3.6.8, then pyvips >>> works!**