# question about NumPy errors in Python libraries.(Numpy User Warning: Loaded more than 1 DLL)

Tags: python, numpy, dll, pycharm

This is a question related to numpy among the Python modules.

I am trying to run python using pycharm on two servers.

In the Windows server 2018 datacenter operating system, the following error appears, but it runs.

```
C:\Users\appuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:30: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:

C:\Users\appuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.EL2C6PLE4ZYW3ECEVIV3OXXGRN2NRFM2.gfortran-win_amd64.dll

C:\Users\appuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.XWYDX2IKJW2NMTWSFYNGFUWKQU3LYTCZ.gfortran-win_amd64.dll

   warnings.warn("loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:"
```

However, in Windows server 2016 datacenter operating system, the above error occurs and it does not run.

What's the problem?

I tried deleting them one by one in anticipation of a problem that occurs when there are more than one file in that folder, but it doesn't work.

Comment: how about using a `venv` to create a vritual environment and separate the dependencies and not have two versions of the same library in the same `venv` ? that would be much better in the long run than trying to get this to work with the current messed up situation.

Comment: How did you get 2 *.dll*s there? What's the *NumPy*'s version? What does "it doesn't work" mean? This should go away by reinstalling *NumPy* (cleaning any remaining *.dll* after uninstalling). Might want to check [\[SO\]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546).

Answer (score 2):

go to the path shown in the warning message such as:

C:\Users\yourUsername.conda\envs\yourEnvName\Lib\site-packages\numpy.libs

it will show two DLL files delete one of them

[image: in my case i deleted the second one]

Answer (score 0):

go to python-path\Lib\site-packages\numpy.libs
if you found 2 or more libs, just lets one and delete all other libs.
this solution will be fix it, i think.