# Trouble importing local libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, dllimport

I have been given a task to package my program and libraries in such a way that anyone with python can run it.
I'm trying to import numpy in a system using the numpy package folder I have , in the same directory as python code(I got the numpy folder from other system I use , where numpy works fine ).

I get this error when I import numpy:

```
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

.....



Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
```

I did all these:

1)Made sure the python and numpy versions match (3.10.8 and 1.24.1)
2)Tried adding numpy folder to sys.path using both append and insert
3)Installed Microsoft c++ redistribute as C compiler is required
4)Added both python path and numpy path to system variables
5)Checked a hundred times if my numpy folder is same in both systems
5)Created a new environment and repeated all the steps above

The issue still pertains . PLEASE HELP !!
(Note - My intention is not to install it using pip or any other command , I'm aware of that method. I want to run programs by just using the library /module folder that I have in the local system)

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add your code (and commands) that trigger the behavior. As for the error, check: [\[SO\]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546) :) .