# Ctypes LoadLibrary gives FileNotFoundError -- do you have to include header files when loading a C++ DLL in Python with ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, dll, shared-libraries, ctypes

I am attempting to load two C++ DLLs in a Python program using ctypes, however, one of the modules throws an error despite the other loading completely fine. Here is the code:

```
import ctypes

os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\Users\{user}\PycharmProjects\pythonProject")

A = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("A.dll")
B = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("B.dll")
```

As stated, I am trying to load two DLLs, let's say we have "A.dll" and "B.dll".

"B.dll" is dependent on "A.dll", so I am loading "A.dll" first. This load works, so we know the libraries are located in the correct directory. However, when attempting to load "B.dll", this error is thrown:

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'B.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Since we know they are located in the correct directory, the issue could only be that it could not locate one of its dependencies. However, I already loaded the library that "B.dll" is dependent on, so I'm not sure what exactly could be missing.

When using this library elsewhere, such as in native C++ code, it is a requirement to also include the library's header file, for example "B.h". I'm wondering if that could be the issue here - is it necessary to somehow include the header file that is associated with "B.dll" in order to be located by ctypes?

Comment: Are you sure b.dll doesn't have some other dependency that isn't being found?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I ran b.dll through DependencyWalker and the only dependencies listed were a.dll and two other windows libraries, which were "ws2_32.dll" and "kernel32.dll". I went ahead and included those in the folder and imported them but b.dll still fails to load. I didn't expect this to work because it hasn't been a requirement to import those when using the dll in C++ programs. So, I'm not sure what other dependency could be missing.

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The "obfuscation" part (*{user}*, *A.dll*, ...) just seems silly.

Comment: @CristiFati Apologies, though I'd rather not share my personal name and the library names are quite long - I thought I might make things more straightforward.

Comment: What *Python* version are you using? [\[SO\]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546)
 (and referenced *URL*s) might help.

Comment: @CristiFati The environment is using Python 3.10. I downloaded [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) from your [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546) and opened B.dll, again it's showing that the only dependencies are: 1. **A.dll** 2. **WS2_32.dll** 3. **kernel32.dll**. I can provide a screenshot if needed.

Comment: Probably it would help. Make sure paths are visible. Also include the whole run output.

Comment: @CristiFati Hi, I was able to get it working by changing the search path directly to the location where the DLL was compiled, which contained the source code. I suppose it was searching for some ambiguous dependencies from that directory. Thanks!

Comment: for anybody else that might be facing the same issue I was able to fix it adding -static flag to gcc