# Loading a .so file with ctypes from an anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, ipython, ctypes

I have created a shared object file "myFile.so" that I am able to load and use via ctypes using the base anaconda environment without issue.

For example, I have no problem doing the following:

```
import ctypes
clibrary = ctypes.CDLL(r"C:\Users\FirstName LastName\Documents\Project\myFile.so")
clibrary.doThings(ctypes.c_int(10), ctypes.c_float(0.6))
```

However, when I activate a virtual environment "testEnvironment" and use the same code I get the following error:

> 

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\FirstName LastName\Documents\Project\myFile.so' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Since the problem seems to involve the way in which anaconda environments search for things, I tried copying the value of os.environ["PATH"] from my base environment to the testEnvironemnt, but received the same error after running the code.  I also tried navigating directly to the folder where the file "myFile.so" is located and running the code from there, but again no luck.

**Update**

The base python environment was using python version 3.8.5, while the virtual environment was using python version 3.10.6.  I created a new virtual environment using python version 3.8.5 and the above code ran without issue.  Therefore the problem appears to be related a change that has occurred between these python versions rather than something related to anaconda environments.

**Update 2**

I still have not found a way to solve the problem in version 3.10.6.  However, I also tested version 3.9.15 and the code ran without issue.

Comment: How did you build your file? What are the *Python* versions involved? Why didn't you name it *myFile.dll*?

Comment: @CristiFati thanks for your response.  It looks like the virtual environment is a newer version of python (3.10.6) versus 3.8.5 for the base environment.  I just tested creating another environment with python version 3.8.5, and this environment is able to run the code without issue like the base environment.  It seems like there has been a change between these two versions of python.  I believe my question is now reduced to: "what is the correct way to do this in python 3.10?"

Comment: Strange. I can't reproduce. Maybe the environment is messed up (or there's something with your file - can you share it?)? Also I asked 2 questions that didn't get answered. Maybe [\[SO\]: PyWin32 and Python 3.8.0 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632354/4788546) will help.